# Display Graph using Boost Graph Library

Tags: boost, graph

Can anyone please tell me that once I've created a graph using Boost Graph library, how can I display that graph?

My biggest concern is that the edge weights are coming from an exernal data source over the network. And I need to be able to display the edgeweights live as they get updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Displaying graphs is a little bit harder then you seem to imagine. Your best bet is to use [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) through [write_graphviz](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/doc/write-graphviz.html) to create a visual representation of your graph.

Updating that graph "live" is a lot harder and you won't get anywhere with [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/)  but would need some real-time-graphics API and graph layouting algorithms that work continously.

Comment: I'm not aware of any open source graph visualization libraries that let you "edit" the visual representations that they produce, and, unfortunately, commercial ones are pretty expensive.

Comment: @Eric Guess he would have to hack it himself. Sounds like fun though. Some 2D OpenGL wrapper for graphs + layout algorithm + animation of layout transitions.

Comment: Well, can you guys please give me some starting point that I can start looking into. 

What sort of real-time-graphics API have you guys used or can you recommend?